# Trying to name a list using a value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a system where a user chooses how many bots he wants to face against from 1 to 3 in a game but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to automatically create the bots using the given value as a name.

```
while True:
    try:
        Player_Count = int(input("How many bots do you want to play against from 1 - 3?"))
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not a number! Try again!")
    else:
        if 1 <= Player_Count <= 3:
            break
        else:
            print("Out of Range! Try Again")
```

That part works fine, but I can't figure out how to use the `Player_Count` variable as a name for the lists (The data for the bots will be stored in those lists.)

I've did this but it's a pretty bad way to do that, I suppose:

```
for bot in range(Player_Count):
    if bot == 0:
        bot1 = []
    if bot == 1:
        bot2 = []
    if bot == 2:
        bot3 = []
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use python dictionary, where bot is key and list is value and then as bot and list are mapped you can access them easily.

Comment: Don't use dynamic variables, use a *container* like a list or a dict

Answer (score 3):

Make a list of lists, where each bot has its own inner list, and the total number of bots is determined by the inputted `player_count`:

```
player_count = int(input("How many bots do you want to play against from 1 - 3?"))
bots = [list() for _ in range(player_count)]
```

You can find the number of bots by `len(bots)`, and index into `bots` to find each individual box.